# Django LoginView() return a Nonetype

Tags: django-forms, django-views

This is views:

```
   class LoginView(View):
    def get(self,request):
        return render(request,'login.html',{})
    def post(self,request):
        login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            user_name = request.POST.get("username", '')
            pass_word = request.POST.get("password", '')

            user = authenticate(username=user_name, password=pass_word)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'index.html') 
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {"msg": "User name or password error!"})
```

This is forms:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)  
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, min_length=5)
```

Here is the login verification why login_form return a NoneType,I return an NoneType whether I login to submit any parameter._bound_fields_cache is None,_errors is None.So what should I write?